# Lambda функция Python

Tags: python, lambda

Хочу сделать сортировку с помощью лябмда функции. Но ошибка

```
def makeRecommendation (userID, userRates, nBestUsers, nBestProducts): 
    matches = [(u, distCosine(userRates[userID], userRates[u]))  for u in userRates if u != userID] 
    bestMatches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x,y : y[0] , reverse=True)[:nBestUsers] 
    print ("Most correlated with '%s' users:" % userID)
    for line in bestMatches: 
        print (" UserID: %6s Coeff: %6.4f" % (line[0], line[1]) )
    sim = dict() 
    sim_all = sum([x[1] for x in bestMatches])
    bestMatches = dict([x for x in bestMatches if x[1] > 0.0]) 
    for relatedUser in bestMatches: 
        for product in userRates[relatedUser]: 
            if not product in userRates[userID]: 
                if not product in sim: 
                    sim[product] = 0.0 
                sim[product] += userRates[relatedUser][product] * bestMatches[relatedUser]
    for product in sim: 
        sim[product] /= sim_all 
    bestProducts = sorted(sim.iteritems(), key = lambda x,y: x[0], reverse=True)[:nBestProducts] 
    print ("Most correlated products:")
    for prodInfo in bestProducts: 
        print (" ProductID: %6s CorrelationCoeff: %6.4f" % (prodInfo[0], prodInfo[1]) )
    return [(x[0], x[1]) for x in bestProducts]
```

Comment: Какая именно ошибка?

Comment: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Comment: В `lambda` приходит один аргумент, но в виде кортежа. Так что оставьте лямбде один параметр и разбирайте его через индексы и т.д.

Comment: Кстати, метод iteritems есть у словаря в Python2, но его нет в Python3 (есть items). Какая версия Python у вас?

Comment: Python3 у меня сейчас

Comment: Тогда iteritems у вас работать не будет.